# Cancelling a background worker which is continuously reading from a network stream

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, backgroundworker, client-side

I have a TCP server running which spits out messages of 2 bytes at regular intervals.

I'm trying to create a client side form which connects to the server and continuously reads from the stream until I click a disconnect button on the form.

So far the client works fine except that I cannot disconnect. I set the CancellationPending to true but it seems to reset back to false before the dowork method gets a chance to set e.Cancel.

I'm also sure there must be a more acceptable way of continuously reading the stream and writing to the form - at the moment I am calling RunWorkerAsync within the Worker Completed method to achieve the loop!

```
    private void Disconnect()
    {
        commsWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }

    private void ReadFromStream()
    {
        try
        {
            commsWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            writeToBox("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    //background worker dowork method
    private void BackGroundGetServerData(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (true == commsWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Byte[] dataArray = new Byte[2];
            try
            {
                _DataStream.Read(dataArray, 0, 2);
                String reply = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataArray);
                e.Result = reply;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    //background worker workercompleted method
    private void BackGroundDisplayMessages(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            //close connection here
        }
        else
        {
            writeToBox((String)e.Result);
            commsWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you set WorkerSupportsCancellation to true?

Comment: Sorry yes, should have noted, both WorkerSupportsCancellation and WorkerSupportsProgress are both true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just loop inside the background worker method?

```
private void BackGroundGetServerData(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while(true)
    {
        Byte[] dataArray = new Byte[2];
        try
        {
            _DataStream.Read(dataArray, 0, 2);
            String reply = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataArray);
            e.Result = reply;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Then upon disconnect simply close the socket. This will cause the `Exception` to be thrown in the while loop and you can exit gracefully through the `catch` block.

`Edit`: Then you can update the GUI from the loop after each message is read. Make sure the handle to the control you are updating is available (assuming it's called `box`):

```
delegate void updateDelegate(String p);

private void BackGroundGetServerData(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while(true)
    {
        Byte[] dataArray = new Byte[2];
        try
        {
            _DataStream.Read(dataArray, 0, 2);
            String reply = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataArray);
            box.BeginInvoke(new updateDelegate(writeToBox), reply);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

`BeginInvoke` is required in this case because you are trying to update the GUI from another thread, which is not allowed. This method forwards the update to the GUI thread.

Comment: How does the BackGroundDisplayMessages get called in this case? If I loop within the DoWork method then, I thought, the WorkerCompleted method would never be called so the values read from the stream would never be displayed?

Comment: Thanks Tudor, much appreciated, I went with your approach and it does the job!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are invoking RunWorkerAsync() in the worker complete method and that resets your CancellationPending prop. I think you can try to fix this by adding to Disconnect() method some disconnectFlag = true; and in WorkerComplete method you should add:

```
if (e.Cancelled || disconnectFlag)
    {
        disconnectFlag = false;
        //close connection here
    } else ...
```